# Wrong path to access subfolders with powershell

Tags: powershell

i'm trying to code a simple script in powershell to change the value of the Language file for every subfolder of a path.

Everything works fine when i'm changing just one Locale file with a hard-coded variable.
But when i try to get all the subfolders from my path and do a foreach loop, the path of the subfolder i get is the concatenation of the path i'm currently in and the path of my subfolder.

Why is that and how can i change this ?

**My code :**

```
$simsPath = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Sims"

$Languages = @{
    "Chinese (Simple)"             = "zh-CN"
    "Chinese (traditional)"        = "zh-TW"
    ...
    "Swedish"                      = "sv-SE"
    "Thai"                         = "th-TH"
}

$correctInput = $false

$Languages.Keys | ForEach-Object { Write-Host $_ }

do {
    $Language = Read-Host -Prompt "`nType the language you want for your game"
    $Language = $Language.ToLower()

    if ((Get-ItemProperty -Path (Join-Path $simsPath "The Sims 3")).Locale -eq $Languages[$Language]) {
        Write-Host "Your game is already in $($Language.ToLower()) ! "
    }
    elseif ($Languages["$Language"]) {
        $correctInput = $true
        Write-Host "You chose '$($Language.ToLower())'"

        try {
            $simsFolders = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $simsPath | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer }

            foreach ($folder in $simsFolders) {
                Set-ItemProperty -Path $folder -Name "Locale" -Value "$($Languages["$Language"])"
                
                if ((Get-ItemProperty -Path $folder).Locale -eq $Languages[$Language]) { 
                    Write-Host "Changed the language for $folder"
                }
                else{
                    Write-Host "Something went wrong, couldn't change the language for $folder."
                    break
                }
            }
            
        }
        catch {
            Write-Host "An unexpected error occurred: $_"
        }
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "Couldn't recognize the language, try again." -ForegroundColor yellow
    }
} while (-not $correctInput)`
```

**My problem :**

For example, i executed my script and tried to change the language to thai

Type the language you want for your game: thai
You chose 'thai'
Set-ItemProperty : Cannot find path
'C:\Users\mylue\Documents\Bordel\TS3\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Sims\The Sims 3' because it does not
exist.
At C:\Users\mylue\Documents\Bordel\TS3\changeLanguage.ps1:52 char:17

- ...             Set-ItemProperty -Path $folder -Name "Locale" -Value "$($ ...
- ```
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\mylue...Sims\The Sims 3:String) [Set-ItemProperty], ItemNotFo
    undException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetItemPropertyCommand

Comment: Use a file explorer and see what subfolders exist under 'C:\Users\mylue\Documents\Bordel\TS3  The code doesn't make sense.  You are merging a diskdriver path with a registry path (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Sims\The Sims 3).  Is the code posted from changeLanguage.ps1?  The error is on line 52 of the ps script.  Your code only has 49 lines.

Comment: @jdweng hi, thank you for your answer ! There's no subfolder under C:\Users\mylue\Documents\Bordel\TS3, but it's where my script changeLanguage.ps1 is. Also, my code has actually 70 lines, i just cutted the language map to make it shorter 

I know merging diskdriver path and registry path doesn't make sense, it's not my intention to do so, the thing is idk why this happens ! When i do Write-Host $folder in my foreach loop i do get the registry path exclusively, i don't know which part of my code merges it with the diskdriver path and how to fix it...

Comment: Okay nevermind, i found it. i just needed to use folder.PSPath  (i didn't think to test other folder attributes since $folder.FullName returned null sorry about that )